# Swift Saving Deleted Rows To Core Data

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, delete-row

Bit of a beginner here so probably shouldn't be trying core data stuff but anyway, I would like to be able to delete a row by swiping. I have done this but it doesn't save the deleted cells and they come back again. I am using a xcdatamodeld file. If anyone can tell me how to save the deleted files to core data that would be great!

Here is my saving data code:

```
inputAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in

        let taskTextField = inputAlert.textFields?.first
        let descTextField = inputAlert.textFields?.last

        if taskTextField?.text != "" && descTextField?.text != "" {
            taskItem.task = taskTextField?.text
            taskItem.desc = descTextField?.text

            do {
                try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                self.loadData()
            }catch {
                print("Could not save data \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
```

Here is the code I have so far for the deleting:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {
        tasks.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: You're must be delete from the model ! For example: Get the current managed object from the indexPath and call the managed object context to delete this object from the model and save this changes. And you'll be Ok. If you're new to the Core Data? I'm strongly recommended use the NSFetchedResultsController class, because it's especially designed for the UITableView

Answer (score 0):

Don't let the fact that you are a beginner keep you from using this powerful persistent store friend. CoreData is a big topic, books have been written on it, but it is something that works very well once you understand the core concepts of programming with it. It looks like you want to remove data that is populated in a `UITableView` and then save what you deleted into CoreData. Let's break down the steps and give you some examples to work with in your own project.

**1) Remove data from your `UITableView`'s datasource**

**2) Save `NSManagedObject` to CoreData**

**3) Delete row from `UITableView`**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete {

        // 1)
        let task = tasks.remove(at: indexPath.row)

        // 2)
        saveToCoreData(task: task)

        // 3)
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
}

// Assuming your task is of type "`Task`". You should put whatever data type your task object actually is.
func saveToCoreData(task: Task) {

    // Insert Into CoreData (very important)
    let managedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "RemovedTask", into: self.context)

    // assign values
    managedObject.value = task.value

    // Save CoreData Context (also, very important)
    do {
        self.context.save()
    }
    catch {
        print("Could not save CoreData!")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, just want to thank you for giving a detailed answer. But, I have a problem. Because 'task' is declared in one function, I get the error 'use of undeclared type' error in my saveToCoreData function. Any ideas?

Comment: I wrote all this in the editor. I didn't have the compiler to inform me about this issue. Look at my edited answer.

Comment: @LukeRoberts keep in mind this isn't a 100% copy and paste job. You have to change the `saveToCoreData(task:)` to input the correct data type. And you also have to ensure your `xcdatamodeld` has an entity called "RemovedTask" or whatever else you'd like to call this in the Core Data model to insert to.

Comment: hi, sorry to have yet another problem! I get the following error: 'value of type 'taskviewcontroller' has no member 'context''. Any ideas?

Comment: That is a placeholder for your managed object context. Replace with `managedObjectContext`.

Comment: Hi, Ive done all the stuff you have said to do but yet again, another error! Under the assign values section, I get this error: "Ambiguous reference to member value(forKey:)". Any ideas?